# MacOS and swift change/set file creationDate

Tags: swift3, attributes, creation

macOS sierra, iMac, swift3

I am trying to write a program that will change the creation date of a file.
I have a lot of scanned photos and documents that I wish to be able to store in alphabetical or chronological order.

I have achieved this in Objective-C but am struggling in swift.
The Apple API  > Foundation > FileManager > setAttributes  instance method should solve my problem.
Instance method ----- setAttributes(*:ofItemAtPath:)
Declaration --- f**c setAttributes(* attributes: [FileAttributeKey : Any], ofItemAtPath path: String) throws

I am unable to write this line of code so that it will compile.

```
var isChangedBoolean = try fm.setAttributes(myAttributesDictionary: [FileAttributeKey : creationDate],ofItemAtPath : myPath)
```

############## My code

```
    let fm = FileManager()
    let myPath = "/Users/jon/a-1.jpg"  //original date  30/1/2013  = d/m/y

    //Convert date string to date object
    let myDateString = "24/11/2014"  // required date
    let dateFmt = DateFormatter()
    //dateFmt.timeZone = NSTimeZone.default
    dateFmt.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
    let myDateObject = dateFmt.date(from : myDateString)
    print("myDateString :\(myDateString) myDateObj :\(myDateObject!)")

    //declare Mutable Dictionary with key : creationDate   and my value
    var myAttributesDictionary = [FileAttributeKey : Date]()
    myAttributesDictionary[FileAttributeKey.creationDate] = myDateObject

    print("-----------------  mtAttributesDictionary")
    print(myAttributesDictionary)
    print(myAttributesDictionary[FileAttributeKey.creationDate]!)  // works
    print("### Will print myAttributesDictionary and a value for the key")   // works

    do
    {
        let fileAttributes =  try fm.attributesOfItem(atPath : myPath)  //works
        //print(fileAttributes)
        print("### Will print File Attributes")
    }
    catch let error as NSError
    {   print("ERROR  READ Attributes: \(error)") }


    do
    {
        print("### Will print my creationDateObject  :: \(myAttributesDictionary[FileAttributeKey.creationDate]!)")
 //  This line is my problem.  I cannot write a line of code that will compile
 //  var isChangedBoolean = try fm.setAttributes(myAttributesDictionary: [FileAttributeKey : creationDate],ofItemAtPath : myPath)
    }
    catch let error as NSError
    {   print("ERROR    ERROR  in setAttributes: \(error)") }

     }
```

Output -----
    myDateString :24/11/2014 myDateObj :2014-11-23 13:00:00 +0000
    myAttributesDictionary
    [__C.FileAttributeKey(_rawValue: NSFileCreationDate): 2014-11-23    13:00:00 +0000]
    2014-11-23 13:00:00 +0000
    ### Will print myAttributesDictionary and a value for the key
    ### Will print File Attributes
    ### Will print my creationDateObject  :: 2014-11-23 13:00:00 +0000

If the line in question code is uncommented it will not compile.  I have written it at least 50 times and have had many different types of compiler errors.  I just don't understand what the API is requiring and I cannot find a working example.
Any suggestions would be much appreciated.  A solution would be even more appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Did I make this complicated.

```
let mypath = "/path/to/file"
let myDateObject = NSDate()       // NSDate()  is todays date

let attributes = [FileAttributeKey.creationDate: myDateObject]

do {
        try FileManager.default.setAttributes(attributes, ofItemAtPath: myPath)
  } 
  catch 
  {
        print(error)
  }
```